# Grades in masters before PhD

Tags: graduate-admissions, grades

I'm working on a masters in mathematical finance. I am going to make at least one B this semester at a program which is not highly regarded after having made very good grades in undergraduate school at a decent university. I was wondering how significant this is if I wanted to apply for doctoral programs in math or physics in the future.

Comment: One B is not significant.  However, a physicist is going to be very confused about why you got a masters in mathematical finance if you want to get a PhD in physics.

Comment: @Anonymous Physicist: Most likely math.

Comment: What @AnonymousPhysicist is saying is that mathematical *finance* seems to have little in common with physics. Their biggest question would be why you pursued a master's degree in mathematical finance, not why you got a B.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: **Don't Panic!**

If you search for [Bad Grade](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=bad%20grade) on this site you get a lot of questions from students in a similar/worse situation. In this case I can just talk for me and for my case and let the other questions talk for themselves: I'm currently a PhD-student and I've gotten among others one B, one C and even one D in courses during my masters. In the end nobody cared because I've written an really good thesis and (at least here at my university and group) that's way more important. So focus on what's ahead of you.

So all in all it is of **no** significance (or at least should not be).